# I have a problem resetting my AppleID password

Tags: apple-id

I tried to reset my AppleID password but I do not remember the Email account or the security questions I used to create the AppleID. Is there anyway to change or find the email I used for my AppleID?

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

If the Apple ID is still logged in the iPad, you can view the email address used by the iCloud account in Settings > iCloud. (Email address appears under the name on the iCloud account)

[image: iCloud settings pane]

From there, you can retrieve the email address used to register the iCloud account and attempt to recover your password.

Comment: the ipad in the moment of active ipad... i cant reach the settings